# I am trying to test new feature of "yatra.com" by selenium, but not getting code how to click on book ticket?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-rc

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class yatra {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
FirefoxDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.yatra.com");
driver.findElement(By.className("iconBeta")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[contains(@id,'nlp_query')]")).sendKeys("go air evening flight from Mumbai to Chennai coming Sunday");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[contains(@id,'nlp_submit')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.className("new-blue-button fr book-button js-bookNow")).click();
```

}}

Comment: Please share the error that you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Class name `new-blue-button fr book-button js-bookNow` you are using for `Book Now` is become available only after you click or hover on that button. Hence Selenium is not able to identify the locator.

Instead write some relative xpath like below. It should work. This one is for First button, for second third etc, change the index number of first div (`div[7]`, `div[8]` with be for second, `div[9]` with be for 3rd etc. )

```
//div[7]/article/div[1]/ul/li[5]/div/p[2]
```

Comment: hi sir,thanks for reply I am very new to automachine world

Comment: "driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BOMMAAG8303G820160911']/div[1]/ul/li[5]/div/p[2]")).click();"  i added that line by taking xpath of it but still facing same error, can u explain me my error and help me how to get into book now?

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me, plese check & revert

```
driver.get("http://www.yatra.com");
driver.findElement(By.className("iconBeta")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[contains(@id,'nlp_query')]")).sendKeys("go air evening flight from Mumbai to Chennai coming Sunday");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[contains(@id,'nlp_submit')]")).click();
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='js-flightRow js-flightItem ng-scope']//div[@class='my-res-info full']//span[contains(text(),'Book Now')])[last()]"));

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", we);
```